# Como permitir copiar e colar em uma tela?

Tags: javascript, struts2

Saudações pessoal,

Tenho um arquivo genérico javascript util.js com uma function para não permitir copiar e colar.

```
    $('input').bind('copy paste', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Em uma página específica, eu preciso que determinado campo permita copiar e colar e não queria me desfazer do util.js que não permite nas demais páginas da aplicação. 
Existe algum jeito de permitir colar? Ou desligar essa validação para a página específica?

Obrigado

Edit1: Chamei o método unbind(); direto na página dessa forma e funcionou

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("input").unbind();
```

Porém, funciona para todos os inputs da tela. Tentei passar o id/nome do campo como parâmetro mas não funcionou. O ideal seria que apenas um campo permitisse copiar e colar.

Obrigado desde já

Edit2:

O campo que precisa permitir copiar e colar é esse:

```
<td width="306" align="center">
                                <s:textfield id="idDesc%{#rowStatus.index}" cssClass="bg_input txtTable" cssStyle="%{listDespRec[#rowStatus.index].listError[2].aplicarCss}" name="listDespRec[%{#rowStatus.index}].observacaoLancamento" value="%{listDespRec[#rowStatus.index].observacaoLancamento}" size="35"  maxlength="30"/>
</td>
```

Alguma sugestão de como passar esse campo no unbind?

Dessa forma aqui não está funcionando

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#listDespRec[%{#rowStatus.index}].observacaoLancamento').unbind('copy paste');
```

Comment: Se vc colocar o código acima na página que quer o copiar e colar sem o preventDefault, não funciona?

Comment: Opa @LeAndrade, obrigado por responder. Não funciona, acredito que a primeira validação prevalece sobre a validação da página

Comment: Sim, isso ocorre porque o listener de validar não foi removido. Você poderia compartilhar o **util.js**  tambem para facilitar a resposta ?

Comment: Opa @MarcosJunior, obrigado pela resposta. O arquivo util.js contém apenas essa validação de copiar e colar que é chamada na inicialização de todas as páginas. Como editei na pergunta, passando o unbind(); direto na página que preciso alterar, ele permite copiar e colar. A questão agora é o campo, pois todos os inputs estão desabilitando o bind('copy paste'). Passando o id/nome do campo, não funcionou. O ideal seria desabilitar apenas para o campo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução faça o unbind para para input específico.

Exemplo:

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", handler );
$( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
```

Exemplo prático

```js
$('input').bind('copy paste', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('#permitecopiar').unbind('copy paste');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<form >
  Não permite colar: <input type="text"><br> Permite colar: <input id="permitecopiar" type="text"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Adicionei o campo na pergunta, pois passando o `id` do jeito que você sugeriu não funcionou

Comment: O mais provável é que não esteja a usar o id apropriado, pode confirmar na consola do chrome $('#o_seu_id') se está correcto

Comment: <input type="text" name="listDespRec[4].observacaoLancamento" size="35" maxlength="30" value="Descrição" id="idDesc4" class="bg_input txtTable" style="">                      O nome do campo é um valor de uma lista.        Passando dessa forma $('#listDespRec[%{#rowStatus.index}].observacaoLancamento').unbind('copy paste'); não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Cara se eu entendi bem seria algo assim certo?

```js
// Não permitir o copy/paste
$('input').bind('copy paste', (e) => false);

// Permitir
$('.copy_paste_on').unbind('copy paste');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="campo 1">
<input class="copy_paste_on" placeholder="campo 2">
<input placeholder="campo 3">
```

No seu exemplo não esta funcionando por esta faltando avisar qual o tipo do **unbind** segue exemplo de unbind:

```
.unbind( eventType [, handler ] )
```